# Angular 4. Reference to elements and apply style

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I reference to a group of elements with same #attribute, and **apply styles to them**?

```
<div #slide></div>
<div #slide></div>
```

I've tried to use `ViewChildren, ViewChild and ElementRef`.

```
@ViewChildren('slide') slides:ElementRef;
ngOnInit($window, scope): void {console.log(this.slides)}
```

But it logs `undefined`.

Comment: Why not just use `[ngStyle]` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `ngOnInit` cycle call as soon Component gets instantiated & before loading `Component` html into DOM tree. You should do it inside [**`ngAfterViewInit`**](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) lifecycle hook, As it make sure that inner content & components are loaded into DOM.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.slides)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you may want to look into creating a custom directive to achieve your task. There, you would use host binding instead. It might end up being cleaner since you're putting IDs all over the place anyways and you can make it reusable outside of that parent component.